# Finding shortest circuit in a graph that visits X nodes at least once

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Even though I'm still a beginner, I love solving graph related problems (shortest path, searches, etc). Recently I faced a problem like this :

> Given a non-directed, weighted (no negative values) graph with N nodes and E edges (a maximum of 1 edge between two nodes, an edge can only be placed between two different nodes) and a list of X nodes that you must visit, find the shortest path that starts from node 0, visits all X nodes and returns to node 0. There's always at least one path connecting any two nodes.
>
> Limits are 1 <= N <= 40 000 / 1 <= X <= 15 / 1 <= E <= 50 000

Here's an example :

[image]

The red node ( 0 ) should be the start and finish of the path. You must visit all blue nodes (1,2,3,4) and return. The shortest path here would be :

> 0 -> 3 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 with a total cost of 30

I thought about using Dijkstra to find the shortest path between all X (blue) nodes and then just greedy picking the closest unvisited X (blue) node, but it doesn't work (comes up with 32 instead of 30 on paper). Also I later noticed that just finding the shortest path between all pairs of X nodes will take O(X*N^2) time which is too big with so much nodes.

The only thing I could find for circuits was Eulerian circuit that only allows visiting each node once (and I don't need that). Is this solveable with Dijkstra or is there any other algorithm that could solve this?

Comment: Do you need an exact answer, or will an approximate answer work for you?

Comment: @templatetypedef I need the exact cost of the shortest circuit.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem may be useful.

Comment: It's certainly NP-hard because TSP can be reduced to it, so your graph better be small

Comment: You need to calculate the shortest paths between blue nodes and then you end up with exactly Traveling salesman problem which is NP-complete. Wiki should help you choose the best solution for that.

Comment: You didn't visit node 5. With 1->5->1, shortest path has length 32.

Comment: @Ante There's no need to visit 5. Only the blue ones need to be visited.

Comment: @A.Andevski OK, my mistake :-/

Comment: Finding shortest path between each pair of X nodes is X(X-1)/2 * O(E + N logN). Since X(X-1)/2 <= 105 << N logN, and E ~= N, it is O(N logN). After that it is standard TSP on complete graph with at most 15 nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which likely to be fast enough:
1)Run shortest path search algorithm from every blue node(this can be done in O(X * (E log N))) to compute pairwise distances.
2)Build a new graph with zero vertex and blue vertices only(X + 1 vertices). Add edges using pairwise distances computed during the first step.
3)The new graph is small enough to use dynamic programming solution for TSP(it has O(X^2 * 2^X) time complexity).

Comment: How do I do the first step in O(X * (E log N)))? With Dijkstra my code completes in about 240 seconds with N = 36786 / X = 15 / E = 40493

Comment: You can use Djikstra with priority queue.